# Where is the "wide" CSS class defined in Magento CE?

Tags: css, magento-1.7

The "wide" css class belongs to "li" elements in the address fields (checkout page, registration form).

I haven't found the "wide" class and its properties inside any of the css files. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**default/blank theme:**

skin/frontend/default/blank/css/styles.css start at line 181

**default/default theme:**

skin/frontend/default/default/css/styles.css start at line 184

**default/modern theme:**

skin/frontend/default/modern/css/styles.css start at line 185

...

Comment: I wonder why "style.css" dont come up when using the "inspect element" function in chrome/firefox. It only shows the css file I created for my customizations but not the style.css file

Comment: If you use an IDE, you can search for `class="wide"` in the whole project, because there are many templates where the class is used.

Comment: I found it using an IDE. Thank you. However the "Inspect Element" function in Chrome dont display the class properties. Same behavior with "input-box" class and others.